# touchwiz launcher bug with logcat inside

Tags: samsung

My problem is that when you try to delete any home page, it gives me force close here is video of my problem http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX4ZDOA3ygE&feature=g-upl here is fragment of logcat: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=33046163&postcount=15 maybe anyone could comment about this issue and it cause :) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a non-trivial issue, I'm afraid.  The logcat output you provided didn't actually  give the cause of the issue.

May I suggest that in the meantime you use another launcher?  [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) and [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher) are particularly good replacements for you Note 2, or if you want to get fancy then [TSF shell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tsf.shell) is fun.

Comment: thank you vm for your answer, but i prefer touchwizz because of some features. By the way here is full log https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hxhcjfxkblo5q0/2012-10-20-17-51-04.txt after i got fc i stopped recording.Something wrong with  E/AndroidRuntime( 2827) :/

Comment: The problem is with this line '10-20 17:51:15.815 E/AndroidRuntime( 2827): java.lang.StackOverflowError' which is a fundamental with the code in the touchwiz launcher.  A search shows that other people are having the same issue - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1890276 (although with a different phone). I've asked a question on XDA http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=33070484#post33070484 - may be worth keeping an eye on it